# How much does it cost to steal a panel in the command board?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep

While playing the Command Board mini-game, how many game points are required to steal a command panel from another player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To steal a command panel from another player, you must pay them 5 times the value of the panel.  I.e. if the panel has a value of 363 GP (game points), you will have to land on the panel then pay them 1815 GP to steal it.

To find the value of the panel (on Playstation):

- Press <kbd>Δ</kbd>
- Navigate to the panel you would like to steal
- Press <kbd>X</kbd>
- The `Value` will be shown in GP as the 3rd option